# How to unscramble an RGB image 1024x1024

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I have a colored image 1024x1024 whose rows and columns were randomly shifted, how would I unscramble it without having any information about the original image?

Comment: That’s what backups are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some type of edge detection would likely help as well, otherwise all the edges would glom together as a mass.  How you'd do that I do not know as pixels don't retain edge characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Information has been lost.

There might be heuristics to make a best-effort recovery effort, based on the observation that typically adjacent pixels tend to have similar values (the difference in pixel intensities between neighboring pixels tends to be small).  So, you could try to solve an optimization problem to find the rearrangement that minimizes the sum of pixel intensity differences between all pairs of adjacent pixels.  That might be a non-trivial optimization problem, I don't know.